# Create a nodejs web app that reads data from AZURE. (Stream analytics or Event Hubs or Log analytics)

Tags: node.js, azure, web-applications, powerbi, azure-stream-analytics

I have connected several devices to **Azure Stream Analytics** that will send in various data. ( Temp, light, humidity and etc )

I am not sure how can I **read data Azure Resources** and **display it on my web application** that I've published on **Azure**. For example, reading device_name, device's data.

What I need is probably a sample code that reads some data from Azure and then display it on a simple 'h1' or 'p' tag.

PS: I've seen lots of tutorial that teaches how to publish web app to Azure. But there're hardly any tutorials that specifically teaches how to read and grab data from Azure Resources.

Comment: Do click on "Mark as Answer" on the post that helps you and vote it as helpful, this can be beneficial to other community members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Azure SDK for Node.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node) to manage Azure resources.

This is an example retrive information about an existing event hub. And here is the Azure Node SDK [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/event-hub?view=azure-node-latest).

```
const msRestAzure = require('ms-rest-azure');
const EventHubManagement = require('azure-arm-eventhub');

const resourceGroupName = 'testRG';
const namespaceName = 'testNS';
const eventHubName = 'testEH';
const subscriptionId = 'your-subscription-id';

msRestAzure
  .interactiveLogin()
  .then(credentials => {
    const client = new EventHubManagement(credentials, subscriptionId);
    return client.eventHubs.get(resourceGroupName, namespaceName, eventHubName);
  })
  .then(zones => console.dir(zones, { depth: null, colors: true }))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Yes. This is sometihng similar to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-node-node-c2d. However, does the Azure SDK has a monitor-events.js? Previously, in the iot-hub explorer package, there is a monitor events.js and it is convenient to get the events data.

Comment: I am afraid there is no monitor-events.js for all Azure resources. But for Event Hub, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-node-get-started-receive#receive-events-using-eventprocessorhost

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using some shortcuts. 
And that you are sending events from devices to `EventHub`

So the architecture right now looks like this:

`Device` -> `EventHub` -> `Azure StreamAnalytics`

and `AppService` called `my web application`

`Azure StreamAnalytics` just help you to do some aggregation, calculation and so on. 
On the other hand, you can use e.g. [Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node)

I would suggest to store data in storage e.g. in [Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-nodejs?toc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ftables%2FTOC.json&bc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json)

This is proposed architecture:

`Device` -> `EventHub` -> `Azure StreamAnalytics` or `Azure Function` ->                                                      `Azure Table Storage`

`AppService` <-> `Azure Table Storage`

And later display data in your web app from storage.
Here is example from docs:

[Retrieve an entity by key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-nodejs?toc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ftables%2FTOC.json&bc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json#retrieve-an-entity-by-key)

```
tableSvc.retrieveEntity('mytable', 'hometasks', '1', function(error, result, response){
  if(!error){
    // result contains the entity
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to visualize the output of Azure Stream Analytics is to use Power BI, if you have access to it. In few minutes you can create a dashboard and show values or graph. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-power-bi-dashboard). Your dashboard can be also embedded in your own app using "Power BI embedded".
If you want to create your own application to visualize output, they are several possible ways depending of your latency requirements. E.g. you can output to Cosmos DB or SQL and then use their client library. You can also output to Azure Function and use Signal R to create dynamic page.
Let us know if you have any further question.